# How can I disable the message on Firefox: "Thanks for downloading Firefox. Please help us learn what people like you expect."

Tags: firefox

Firefox is displaying a message that says:

"Thanks for downloading Firefox. Please help us learn what people like you expect."

I need to disable this and ensure it is never displayed in the first place because my application is a kiosk type application.

Even better would be to ensure that no such messages ever appear, but for now I'd be happy to know how to get rid of this message.

[image]

thanks

Comment: See if Firefox Kiosk Mode works. Start Firefox with the `--kiosk` parameter to put it into Kiosk mode.